# VMWare Player - How to pause the guest?

Tags: vmware-player

Is it possible to pause (not suspend) the guest system in VMware Player (currently using v7.1.4)?

VMware Workstation [has this feature](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-CFE06F56-8AF4-4FFF-92B7-675EBA7DEE63.html), is it hidden somewhere in Player (like the NAT settings)?

Comment: This does not appear to be a feature of the version of VMWare Player your using.